# What part is this grey keyhole shape and what set(s) is it from?

Tags: part-identification

I've recently found this grey keyhole-shaped piece - there are a fair number of them that stack together to form a circular staircase. There is what looks like a part number on the bottom but it is unreadable and faint. There is also a number beneath the part number, 201.

(images were made smaller but bigger ones can be added if needed).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bricklink lists it as ["Stairs Spiral Step" (Part# 40243)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=40243). It first appeared in 2001 in the initial series of Harry Potter licensed sets.

Comment: Here is the complete assembly of the staircase: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?P=40243c01

Comment: The second I saw those I thought "Harry Potter for sure."

Called it!

Comment: It is also found in the Lego Batcave (set number 7783).

Comment: Also found in the Hobbit "Barrel Escape" set. In that set though, it's locked in place, so it can't be opened or closed magically like it's supposed to in the Harry Potter sets.

Comment: One of the recent Frozen castles has one - it's only locked in at the bottom though. Set is also notable for having 4 glittery transparent tiny rock pieces :D